# « essayé de s’évader » : How does « essayer de » not presuppose « s'evader »?

Tags: semantics, french, prepositions

<sub>Source: p 175, *French prepositions à and de
in infinitival complements, 
A pragma-semantic analysis* (2008) by Lidia Fraczak, as part of *Adpositions ; Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives*  (2008) edited by D Kurzon, S Adler</sub>

> Concerning the verbs considered as “presupposing” by Adamczewski (1991), it
>   may be observed that what is presupposed by V1 is not always V2 itself but some
>   stage preceding the one represented by V1. Thus, the verb commencer (“to start”)
>   presupposes the stage “to envisage”, “to plan”; the verb continuer (“to continue”)
>   presupposes the stage “to start”; the verb finir (“to finish”) presupposes the stages
>   “to start” and “to continue”; and the verb oublier (“to forget”) presupposes the
>   stage “to think of ”. This kind of presupposition can be called “lexical” and it may
>   be distinguished from “situational” presupposition, where the use of some V1
>   requires that the fact expressed by V2 be presupposed.
>   Some verbs seem to be
>   related to both types of presupposition: for example, oublier in “oublier de + V2”
>   (“to forget to + V2”), on one hand, presupposes the stage “to think of ” and, on the
>   other hand, it will be used in a context where the fact expressed by V2 is presupposed
>   as well.
>   Other verbs, however, while containing “lexical” presupposition, do
>   not require “situational” presupposition. It is the case, for example, with the verb
>   essayer (“to try”) (considered as “presupposing” by Adamczewski), which does
>   presuppose some previous step or stage (“to think of ” or “to plan”) but whose use
>   is not necessarily determined by a presupposition about the fact expressed by V2.
>   Statements like the one below:
>
> (4) *Un prisonnier a essayé de s’évader cette nuit de la prison X.*
>   ‘A prisoner tried to escape from prison X last night.’
>
> **do not allow us to consider that the piece of information related to V2 (“to escape...”
>   in this case) is necessarily presupposed.**

I do not understand the (bolded) last sentence above. How does *essayer de* NOT presuppose the prisoner's escape? The prisoner must have presupposed the possibility of escape before trying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the previous question, *presupposition* (as this writer is using it, but I think it's fairly general) is about what the participants in the conversation know, not about what the participants in the narrative know.